# how to read it into a string without using a readline of String Buffer in android

Tags: java, android

```
public class HttpPosrHitter {

    public static String getJSONfromURL(String url, String member_id,
            String phonenumber) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jArray = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memberid", member_id));
            pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numbers", phonenumber));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

            // http post

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try {

            jArray = new JSONObject(result);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is class from which i am Post Phone Number to web service and getting response .
 when i Post Number of Phone which has 15 to 20 contact i am getting response . but when i post number which has 150 contact i am not getting response one at a time i have to relaunch  app two time then i am getting response . i dont know where i am doing mistake . even i am unable to read phone large file in chunks with fixed size buffer.

Comment: you should post data only once for that you have to change your webservice(web API) just make an jsonarray of member id and nubmer and post it just once and get response.

Comment: for 15 number i am getting response but when input number is large more than 150 then response is not coming i dont know why? we can not change web service

Comment: but making http request many times is not good.

Comment: i know but my issue is not making request many time my issue is different when i number which has 15 ,20 numbers in contact i am getting response one at a time but problem is coming when i post large inpute 150 apprxo Phone number then i am not getting response

Comment: Yes but you are making 150 req. at a time so that you are not getting proper response.

Answer (score 1):

Just to solve all your potential bugs in one single shot: is there anything preventing you from using [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) and [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)?

Each time I see such JSON/InputStream/URLConnection/... questions, I keep wondering why people keep on spending time to reinvent basic stuff instead of actually writing apps.

Comment: u there how to Post or get Using GSON ?

Comment: Go read the Retrofit documentation first (this is for GET/POST). Then you can read about GSON (that is for parsing json).

Answer (score 0):

```
        public class HttpPosrHitter {

        public static String getJSONfromURL(String url, String member_id,
                String phonenumber) {
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("memberid", member_id));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("numbers", phonenumber));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));

                // http post

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                result = EntityUtils.toString(entity); //changes Made

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
            }



            try {

                jArray = new JSONObject(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: NO its nowt working please update it with my code  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
   is = EntityUtils.toString(entity); i mtrying this but

Comment: can u add your web service code so that it helps more understanding about the Problem

Comment: Ok i will Provide u web service also